# Logs stored in storage account monitored by Azure Sentinel

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-storage-account, azure-sentinel

I want to understand if i am sending logs from log analytics workspace to a storage account in azure, is it possible that those logs will be monitored by Azure sentinel when storage connector is used or will azure sentinel only monitor storage account logs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you wish to read the contents of Azure Storage and ingest into Sentinel.  If so, you will need a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/create-custom-connector).  There is an Azure Function example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sreedharande/AzureStorageAccountBlobsIngestion).

[image: Sentinel Custom Connector]

Comment: yes ken, one scenario is if any onprem appliance logs are being stored in azure blob can those logs be read by sentinel to process for any security related events

Comment: yes they can be by a custom connector.  I know the example above looks like a lot, EvenGrid, StrQueue, AzFunction, LogA but it's just an example.  EventGrid is needed to send logs as they land, if you are fine with some time lag you could configure the AzFunction to run periodically.